# Why python list is not passed by reference

Tags: python

I'm doing a homework and my assignment is to make a script that removes highest and lowest prices and prints the middle price here is my code:

```
def removeall(list,value):
    list = [n for n in list if n != value]  
    print(list)
prices = []

while True:
    usrinput = input('Please enter price or stop to stop: ')
    if usrinput == 'stop':
        break

    prices.append(float(usrinput))


print(prices)

highestprice = max(prices)
lowestprice = min(prices)

removeall(prices, highestprice)
removeall(prices, lowestprice)

print(prices)

print(sum(prices)/len(prices))
```

I know that I can make it work like:

```
def removeall(list,value):
    mylist = [n for n in list if n != value]  
    return mylist

prices = removeall(prices,highest)
```

But my question is why removeall() is not changing prices? Isn't it passed by reference?

Comment: Don't use list as a variable name and if you want to change the original list use `lst[:] =[n for n in lst if n != value]` in your function or return it and set prices equal to the value returned. You can also do it all in a single pass if you pass boththe  min and max using `if n not in ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python parameters are not really the same as references in some other languages. It's more like a pointer that's being passed by value. If you modify the pointer to point to something else, the calling code doesn't see the change.

To make a change that can be seen outside the function, you need to modify the list in place. A simple way to do that is to use a slice assignment:

```
list[:] = [n for n in list if n != value]
```

This changes the existing list, rather than just rebinding the `list` variable. (Note, that's a very bad variable name, since it shadows the builtin `list` type. I strongly suggest avoiding it as a local variable name!)

Answer (score 0):

Your `removeall` function isn't altering the list being passed in, it is creating a new list, printing it out then throwing it away.